# Is it ok to return an object in Javascript class?

Tags: javascript, class

What happens if return an object when defining a class constructor?
can I use it for security and avoid accessing the class methods and ...?

for example I have below code:

```js
class X {
  y = ''
  x = 0

  constructor(
    p1,
    p2,

  ) {
    this.p1 = p1
    this.p2 = p2
    return {
      getp1: this.getp1
    }
  }
 getp1 = () => this.p1
}

let x = new X("fo", "bar")
console.log(x.p1) // will be undefined
console.log(x.getp1() ) // will be "fo"
```

as you see `x.p1` is not accessible directly, but I can get `p1` by `getp1` method. can I use it for `private` and `public` methods in javascript?

Comment: What's the point of creating an object if you can't access its attributes or methods?

Comment: why do you want this? if the class does not returnitself, you get the custom object.

Comment: I neither understand what you mean by "*for security*" nor by "*avoid accessing the class methods*"

Comment: @Barmar to define private and public methods and parameters

Comment: But you've effectively made everything private, since you never get the object.

Comment: And with no public methods, how does it do anything? Unless it operates automatically, and everything is triggered from the constructor.

Comment: ^ this is a valid point

Comment: @Barmar Assume everything operates automatically and does not need any public method, everything goes well inside the class, just I need to avoiding access the class methods from outside.

Comment: @MHS ... *"Assume everything operates automatically and does not need any public method"* ... in that case a function, or, in order to meet the aspect of some lifetime, a closure are already sufficient enough.

Answer (score 5):

This would be a better approach.

You can use `#` to make a property or a method "private" which means it can only be accessed by methods or properties inside of that class. the code below demonstrates its usage

```js
class Test {
    #privateValue;
    constructor() {
        this.#privateValue = 10;
    }

    test() {
        return this.#privateValue;
    }
}

const test = new Test();
console.log(test.privateValue)
console.log(test.test())
```